# How do I use Require.js to load specific scripts on specific pages?

Tags: requirejs, jekyll, frontend

I am developing a Jekyll multi-page html project and would like to load jQuery + Carousel js file on the home page, but only jQuery js file on the contact page. How would I leverage Require.js to do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this more efficiently by using Jekyll to determine which scripts are included instead of using JS to determine them.

You can use a per page variable (say, `scripts`) to specify which scripts to load.

For the home page, you'd have:

```
---
scripts:
 -  jquery
 - carousel
---
```

And for the contact page, you'd have:

```
---
scripts
 - jquery
---
```

Then, where you're adding the `<script>` tags, you'd iterate over the `scripts` variable and output a tag for each item.

```
{% for script in page.scripts %}
    <script src="/vendor/js/{{ script }}.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

In this example, the scripts are stored in `/vendor/js/jquery.js` and `/vendor/js/carousel.js`. You could of course change the folder path in the script tag or the file names in the `scripts` variable.